# "Сюжет пересказывался сотни веков снова и снова"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Благовещенье – один из любимейших моих сюжетов в истории искусства. Он
>   пересказывался сотни веков снова и снова.

Что-то не так, но что? *на протяжении сотен веков?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да все очень просто: сотня веков — это (сто умножаем на сто) десять тысяч лет. Нам такой "возраст пересказываний" не подходит (веков-то только двадцать).

Возможно так: на протяжении веков; на протяжении многих веков; многие сотни лет; на протяжении сотен лет; из века в век, уже третье тысячелетие.

Comment: Римма! Вы - гений! Я не сообразила!

Comment: Ой спасибо за добрые слова! (А я ведь тоже не сразу скумекала.)

Comment: Ну почему же двадцать веков? Намного больше. Один только династический период Древнего Египта длился 27 веков.

Comment: Э-э... Древний Египет тут никак "не подходит". _**Благове́щение** Пресвятой Богородицы — евангельское событие и посвящённый ему **христианский** праздник; возвещение архангелом Гавриилом Деве Марии о будущем рождении по плоти от неё **Иисуса Христа**._  Сейчас у нас XXI век от Рождества Христова.